# Linking Error with Simple OpenCV Program

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, linker, clang

I'm new to OpenCV and I can't seem to get a simple program to work. When I try to compile I'm getting linking errors and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp" 
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp" 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main () { 
  VideoCapture webcam = VideoCapture (0); 

  if (webcam.isOpened () == false) { 
    cout << "Opening camera failed." << endl; 
    return 0; 
  } 

  namedWindow ("Webcam", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
  Mat frame; 

  while (true) { 
    webcam >> frame; //OR webcam.read (frame) 
    imshow ("Webcam", frame); 
  } 

  return 0; 
}
```

I'm trying to compile it from the command line using the following command:

```
clang++ Test.cpp -o test -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11_1/include/ -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11_1/lib  -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -stdlib=libstdc++
```

Here is the error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in Test-768b08.o
  "cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in Test-768b08.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9 and I installed OpenCV using Homebrew. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Try: ``clang++ -Wall -g -o test Test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` ``. The last part should conveniently include all locations of the OpenCV libraries when compiling. This should have been configured if you installed OpenCV via Homebrew.

Comment: When I try that I still get the same error

Comment: What's the result of the command `grep -ls imshow /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11_1/lib/*`?

Comment: Are you using Xcode?